# Neo4j - Is there a cypher query syntax to list (show) all indexes in DB?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, indexing

I'm looking for something similar to the MySQL ( SHOW INDEXES ).  I was able to get a list of indexes using py2neo in Python

```
graphDB = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
indexes = graphDB.get_indexes(neo4j.Node)
print(format(indexes))
```

but I wanted to know if there's a way to do something similar in Cypher.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Not yet. In Neo4j 2.0 more cypher friendly indexing was introduced and you can issue some DDL commands to create and drop indices and constraints, but as of 2.01 that's it (see [docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-schema.html)). In 1.9 you can't define that type of schema with cypher at all.

--

There are many ways outside of cypher, for instance

In `neo4j-shell` you can

- list legacy indices with `index --indexes`
- list all label indices and constraints with `schema`
- list indices and constraints for specific label with `schema ls -l :YourLabel`

In `neo4j-browser` you can

- list all label indices and constraints with `:schema`
- list indices and constraints for specific label with `:schema ls -l :YourLabel`

Most APIs that let you execute cypher queries will also provide ways to query schema, such as

- Native Java API

  - `GraphDatabaseService.schema().getConstraints()` and `.getIndexes()` for label schema
  - `GraphDatabaseService.index().nodeIndexNames()` and `.relationshipIndexNames()` for legacy indices
- REST calls to

  - `/db/data/schema/` endpoints for label based schema
  - and to `/db/data/index/node/` and `/db/data/index/relationship/` for legacy indices

Comment: Since I wasn't able to find anything in Cypher I've been using the shell command "index --indexes".

Answer (score 64):

neo4j 3.1 now supports this as a built-in procedure that you can CALL from Cypher:

```
CALL db.indexes();
```

http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.1/reference/procedures/

Answer (score 39):

What about the `:schema` command? (In the Neo4j shell it's just `schema`).

Works like charm for me in Neo4j 2.0.1

Comment: This is useful but not actually part of cypher.

Answer (score 14):

```
CALL db.indexes();
```

is deprecated by new SHOW INDEXES as reported in 4.2

```
SHOW INDEXES
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, in Cypher you cannot do that but there's a REST API request, which works.

You can check it in Terminal.

All indexes in the database:

```
curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index/
```

Indexes on a specific label:

```
curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index/User
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer your question (I +1'd jjaderberg's answer as well.)

In py2neo there is some functionality for labels: http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/schema/

> `get_index(label)` Fetch a list of indexed property keys for a label.

FYI, in shell you can use the undocumented `schema` command.