# How to get all indexes attached to a given label in Neo4J 2.0 Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Does anybody know how to get all the indexes attached to a given label (or all the labels) in Neo4J 2.0 listed?

I've only found this:

http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0-M03/org/neo4j/graphdb/schema/Schema.html#getIndexes(org.neo4j.graphdb.Label)

But how do I do that through Cypher? Or at least REST API?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar kind of problem earlier posted. You can refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801599/neo4j-is-there-a-cypher-query-syntax-to-list-show-all-indexes-in-db

Comment: @SumeetSharma thanks! I posted the answer there as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `:schema` command in the browser and `schema` command in Neo4j shell.

In the Java Core API it is in `db.schema().getIndexes(label)`

Comment: For a specific label, it would be `:schema ls -l :the_label`

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer to my own question inside the main.js file of this great Neo4J Node.Js module: http://github.com/philippkueng/node-neo4j

There is in fact a REST API endpoint, which provides all the indexes in the database:

```
http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index/
```

Indexes on a specific label:

```
http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index/User
```

I only wonder if Neo4J is moving away from REST API towards Cypher - will they offer this functionality in there as well?