# Neo4j : Finding the relationships of only one tag

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find all the children of a particular node.

```
match(t:TAG)<-[children:CHILD_OF]-(subtag:TAG) where t.name="brand" return t.name, subtag.name
```

I am getting the correct result from the query above. But I am doubtful that this query is efficient. As it is first getting all the relationships of "tagA is a child of tagB" and then filtering it where tagB is as given.

There must be a better way to write this. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
match(t:TAG) where t.name="brand" with t 
Match (t)<-[children:CHILD_OF]-(subtag:TAG)  return t.name, subtag.name
```

You can check the difference by using `profile`

Comment: surprisingly my query is faster

Comment: It might be becouse of your data set (you have small number of tags and neo4j optimizes query), cache. And if not it seems strange to me, make sure you have index on name.

Comment: That could be the case. How can I check that I have an index?

Comment: Look here for index info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801599/neo4j-is-there-a-cypher-query-syntax-to-list-show-all-indexes-in-db